# How to keep mac prompt customization when sshing into aws ec2 instances whose ip addresses change when I stop and restart the instance?

Tags: ssh, colors, macintosh, amazon-ec2

Summary: my goal is to have a prompt that's got a different color so I can easily distinguish between command line and output at a glance.

Details: I have configured my mac terminal to show the prompt in a different color than the rest of the text. I set the `PS1` shell variable and added it to the `~/.bash_profile` on the mac terminal. However, when I ssh into an aws ec2 instance I lose that customization. The problem is, I don't know if or how I can configure the mac terminal, so that the customization of the prompt line transfers when I ssh into an aws instance whose ip address keeps changing every time I stop and restart the instance. If there is a better solution (such as a terminal emulator similar to mobaexerm), I'm open to that as well.

Comment: When you log in, you get a shell on the remote machine.  That shell processes its rc files, which typically sets `PS1` -- you probably get some sort of customized prompt on the remote machine.  Even if `ssh` copied the value you set on your mac, it'd get overwritten.

Comment: (It's not the terminal that sets the prompt, but the shell. The terminal merely interprets it.)